# Assert - 2 Exact Same String Comparing Returns Error

Tags: java, string, selenium, gettext

I am comparing two strings using this code:

```
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText().equals(text));
```

Both String outputs are exactly the same in the output:

```
    Merci ! Votre commande a été envoyée.
    Merci ! Votre commande a été envoyée.
```

Tests does run many times, and it always worked until this one situation. 
There are no spaces inside the strings. 
Special characters does not cause problems in any other cases.

Any Thoughts? Thank you!

UPDATE:

I am getting the same error when comparing these strings, maybe have something in common that breaks the test:

```
Merci ! Votre commande a été envoyée.
Merci ! Votre commande a été envoyée.

Référence de la commande : {0}
Référence de la commande : {0}

Contactez-moi !
Contactez-moi !

Quelle est la probabilité que vous recommandiez nous à un ami ou un collègue ?
Quelle est la probabilité que vous recommandiez nous à un ami ou un collègue ?
```

I noticed there is a space before symbol in each case (_! / _? / _:). This (the space before symbol) never occurs in other passing assertions. I am testing like 500 of them. May be the cause?

Comment: What is the situaion

Comment: Isn't `From Page` and `My Test S` different enough to cause the failure?

Comment: no, those are just titles I added. Going to removed them by edit to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: You should try printing your strings surrounded by dashes "-" just to make sure an extra unwanted and unatended space isn't pulling your leg. Outputting the length of your strings may help too.

Comment: Thank you, did not help. I tried dashes, still looks the same. Tried .length, and they are both 37 chars long, still the same.

Comment: yes, call trim() on them before comparison

Comment: No, .trim does not work. It was suggested below :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is, that whitespace around the text are trimmed or added at getText.

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText().equals(text));
```

Probably disregard this difference:

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText().trim()
    .equals(text.trim()));
```

An other property of Unicode is that `é` can be either one char or two (e + accent). And java internally uses Unicode for text. Actually one should [normalize](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) text before comparing.

```
s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFKC); // Most compact
```

By the way instead of `assertTrue` the method `assertEquals` with expected and actual values will give better error messages.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, that came to my mind as well. I will test it in a while and get back to you!

Comment: Resolved. I added normalizer to the strings where I was getting errors and it works like a charm! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Let us see whats happening in your code. You have used :

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText().equals(text));
```

Within `Assert.assertTrue` you are comparing 2 values. The first value is `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText()` which can return `text` (w/out white space characters) or `NULL`. The second value is a pure `text`.

Now, if you look at the javadoc of **`equals`** it is defined as :

```
boolean java.lang.String.equals(Object anObject)
//Compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.
```

This is the root case of your failure. This will return `True` only if the given object represents a `String` equivalent to this string

Again, if you look at the javadoc of **`assertTrue`** it is defined as :

```
void org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(boolean condition)
//Asserts that a condition is true. If it isn't, an AssertionError is thrown.
```

### Solution:

The solution would be to use either **`contains`**, **`equalsIgnoreCase`** or **`contentEquals`** instead of `equals` as follows :

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText().contains(text));
//OR
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(text));
//OR
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText().contentEquals(text));
```

### Update 1:

I will suggest use **`getAttribute("innerHTML")`** instead of **`getText()`** as follows :

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getAttribute("innerHTML").contains(text));
//OR
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getAttribute("innerHTML").equalsIgnoreCase(text));
//OR
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getAttribute("innerHTML").contentEquals(text));
```

### Update 2:

As your test is still failing, I would suggest you to reduce the `expected string` to something substantial instead of the entire string. Example:

```
String text = "Votre commande a été";
```

### Update 3:

As a last resort, you should be able to expand the expected string as follows :

```
String text = "Merci ! Votre commande a été envoyée.";
```

And perform your Test successfully.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Tried all 3 of them, unfortunately none of it worked. There must be some hidden-to-eye difference in those 2 strings.

Comment: No it is not returning null from getText, as I am seeing the outputs during the test. I tried also .getAttribute("innerHTML"), but I got the same result. I updated my question, please check, maybe it helps.

Comment: That does make the test pass. But it's not solution I am looking for, as my requirement is to test the entire element text. Thank you for suggestion anyway!

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, the full length of string caused errors. I did give an upvote to you for patiently trying to help ;) However, normalizer suggested by @Joop Eggen above resolved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use trim and remove empty space and check it.

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText()trim().equals(text.trim()));
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion, unfortunately not working.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

Old:

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText().equals(text));
```

New:

```
Assert.assertTrue(text.equals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelector)).getText()));
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion, unfortunately not working.

Comment: Strings not equal.